# Error: Cannot be accessed directly CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Element file I am calling:

```
      $brand = $this->requestAction('brands/buyer_getnames/');
```

Action file I am calling:

```
    public function buyer_getnames(){
               $newid=$this->Auth->User('brand_id');
                   $name=$this->Brand->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Brand.id'=>$newid),'recursive'=>-1));
    return $name['Brand']['name'];
}
```

Getting error below..!!

```
Private Method in BrandsController

Error: BrandsController::buyer_getnames() cannot be accessed directly.
```

Please help

Comment: Please, provide more context. There are you call  $this->requestAction ?

Comment: is `buyer` a routing prefix?

Comment: @AD7six yes Its a prefix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Request action respects normal url routing rules

If you're using [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) then you can't access `function prefix_foo()` via a url of the form `/controller/prefix_foo` - it needs to be the corresponding prefix url: `/prefix/controller/foo`.

As such your request action call should be:

```
$brand = $this->requestAction('/prefix/brands/getnames/');
```

Note that if the only thing that method does is call a model method, you're better off simply doing:

```
$model = ClassRegistry::init('Brand');
$brand = $model->someMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can allow unauthorized access to action if your action is requested with requestAction method.

**For example:**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if ($this->request->is('requested') && $this->request->params['action'] == 'index') {
        $this->Auth->allow(array('index'));
    }
}
```

This may also work (haven't tested):

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
        $this->Auth->allow(array('index'));
    }
}
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I dont think the latter would work - since the Auth question will have to be answered prior to actually running the index action code!

Comment: some times i face this types of issue, and that was the reason the think is worked for me.