# RequestAction error in cakephp

Tags: html, cakephp

When i doing my project. I trying use this->requestAction to my navbar.
my navbar file in `/elements/nav`

ok. when i try this `<?php $abouts=$this->requestAction('abouts/getNav'); ?>` top of my navbar file. 
Everything work but it appear a 0 digit after body.
 Something like `<body> 0<div>` DO U SEE THAT 0 position? how to remove the 0 digit? and what the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow unauthorized access to action if your action is requested with requestAction method.

For example:

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

```
if ($this->request->is('requested') && $this->request->params['action'] == 'index') {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('index'));
}
```

}
This may also work (haven't tested):

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
        $this->Auth->allow(array('index'));
    }
}
```

or you can use this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345948/error-cannot-be-accessed-directly-cakephp/17347181#17347181)

hope this will sure help you